# BuildCraft waterproof pipes and water/oil pumping, does liquid get lost?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

I found an oil well the other day and have now successfully pumped it dry into a ton of tanks, some 450 tank blocks, spread over 25 high tank towers.

Now I want to refine it.

The question is, do I have to empty each tank at a time, to avoid loosing liquid?

All the tanks are placed next to each other, and let's say I attach a wooden pipe to each, with a running redstone engine above, and then hook everything together into one long pipe network ending up in the refinery.

Obviously the refinery will not be able to refine quick enough that all that oil will flow at the same speed from each tank as it would if I was emptying just one tank, so the pipes will be full pretty quick.

Will the pumps stop drawing oil from the tanks when this happens, so that I can just set it all up and forget about it, assuming I create enough tanks to hold all the fuel that is.

Or do I have to "micromanage" it by emptying out one oil tank at a time, to avoid filling the pipes and then losing liquid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is no room for more liquid in the pipes then no more liquid will be extracted. This can be easily verified with some of the Forestry machines which have internal tanks and a rollover on them which displays in detail how much liquid is currently in the tank.